# SCHEMA_NAME() returns NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the `SCHEMA_NAME()` function in a a T-SQL script.

It returns `NULL` for me, but the default schema for my colleague.

The documentation for `SCHEMA_NAME()` only lists `NULL` as a possible value when one also supplies an argument to the `SCHEMA_NAME()` function.

Here is the documentation for `SCHEMA_NAME()`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/schema-name-transact-sql

What should I look for when debugging this problem?

The DBA has checked that my permissions are same for my colleague and myself.

I am calling the function without any arguments so the documentation's stated case of returning `NULL` when `schema_id` is not valid does not apply -- at least not explicitly.

The DBA confirmed I have a default schema and I used the following select to confirm I have a default schema:

```
select * from sys.database_principles dp where dp.name = USER_NAME();
```

The DBA changed my default schema to something else, then changed it back in case there is something set in the background.

This happens in SQL Studio and when I run on the command line using `sqlcmd`.

I have noticed that when I run `CREATE PROCEDURE myproc` the procedure is created in my default schema, but when I run `execute myproc` I need to do `execute myschema.myproc`.  That is: I *must* specify the schema.

I have verified that the default schema exists by hard coding the schema name in the call to the stored procedure.

Comment: "Returns NULL when schema_id is not a valid ID."   Now how can any of us know whether you are providing the function a valid ID?

Comment: Tab - I think Michael is using the function without parameters.  I've just tried it and get 'dbo' as the result.  Sorry Micheal, I haven't the first idea what could be up here!

Comment: "If schema_id is not defined, SCHEMA_NAME will return the name of the default schema of the caller."   Do you have a valid default Schema set for your login?

Comment: where you run your script in management studio or pragmatically?

Comment: Have you verified the default schema actually exists? `SCHEMA_NAME()` will return `NULL` if not.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen when you are performing query on a different database than the schema_id

e.g.

```
select sn = schema_name(schema_id) from [yourdbname].sys.all_objects
```

and the current database is not [yourdbname]

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue with Schema_name() return null value but sys.database_principal showing default schema as my user name,Then I noticed that schema(username) was deleted by DBA team. When they recreate the same schema. My issue got resolved. You can check the list of schema in database using sys.schemas.

Answer (score 0):

In Security>Logins, right click on your login, click "User Mappings" and see what the default schema is for the database you are in.   Then do the same for your co-worker's login.