# Why the warning about VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE.VIEW_SCHEMA?

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

I recently noticed that the documentation for the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/view-column-usage-transact-sql) view at Microsoft's Docs website contains a warning for both the VIEW_SCHEMA and TABLE_SCHEMA columns:

> **** Important **** only reliable way to find the schema of a object is to query the sys.objects catalog view.
> *[sic]*

There must be a concrete reason for that warning, and only on those two fields. What's the reason for the warning? Is it know under what circumstances can this information_schema view get the schema fields wrong?

I need to know how concerned I should be; and how hard do I need to push for replacing existing code that uses that view.

Answer (score 3):

This may only be a partial answer but perhaps it's sufficient for your or perhaps it can lead someone else to a more complete answer.  But I can tell you that:

```
exec sp_helptext 'information_schema.view_column_usage'
```

returns:

```
SELECT  
 DB_NAME()     AS VIEW_CATALOG,  
 SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id) AS VIEW_SCHEMA,  
 v.name      AS VIEW_NAME,  
 DB_NAME()     AS TABLE_CATALOG,  
 SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS TABLE_SCHEMA,  
 t.name      AS TABLE_NAME,  
 c.name      AS COLUMN_NAME  
FROM  
 sys.views v JOIN sys.sql_dependencies d ON d.object_id = v.object_id  
 JOIN sys.objects t ON t.object_id = d.referenced_major_id  
 JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = d.referenced_major_id  
  AND c.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id  
WHERE  
 d.class < 2
```

As you can see, both `view_schema` and `table_schema` utilize `schema_name()`.  And, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743600/schema-name-returns-null) question and elsewhere, that function is known to sometimes give different results depending on whether your query is cross-database or whether default schema for your user is different from someone else's.

I've never actually seen an information_schema query give unexpected results in a schema field, and perhaps it's not really possible with the output from sys.views and sys.tables (a null schema_id would create the issue), but this general behavior with `schema_name()` may have been sufficient for them to give the disclaimer.